# How to save JSON string array with multiple name/value pair in separate arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I have following JSON string.

```
[ { "id" : "1", "name" : "name1" },
{ "id" : "2", "name" : "name2" },
{ "id" : "3", "name" : "name3" },
{ "id" : "4", "name" : "name4" },
{ "id" : "5", "name" : "name5" } ]
```

How to save it in 2 separate arrays of "id & "name", where id and name arrays have same data as in the original array on a particular index.

Comment: Where are you stuck? Do you know how to iterate an Array? How to access an object property? How to add an item to an array? Please show what you've tried, so we can see what the actual problem is.

Comment: This isn't a code writing service. You are expected to show what you have tried to solve the problem yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data = [ { "id" : "1", "name" : "name1" },
{ "id" : "2", "name" : "name2" },
{ "id" : "3", "name" : "name3" },
{ "id" : "4", "name" : "name4" },
{ "id" : "5", "name" : "name5" } ];

var ids = data.map(function(obj){
      return obj.id;
});

var names = data.map(function(obj){
      return obj.name;
});
```

Use map function

Answer (score 0):

This is a generalised processing, that can work with n number of elements dynamically.

```js
var arr = [{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "name1"
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "name": "name2"
}, {
  "id": "3",
  "name": "name3"
}, {
  "id": "4",
  "name": "name4"
}, {
  "id": "5",
  "name": "name5"
}];
// key is an optional parameter.
// if key is sent only the array having that key is returned.
// else the entire structure is returned.
function processData(arr, key) {
    var obj = {},
      i,
      prop,
      len = arr.length;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
      elem = arr[i];
      for (prop in elem) {
        if (!obj[prop]) {
          obj[prop] = [];
        }
        obj[prop].push(elem[prop]);
      }
    }
    if (key) {
      return obj[key];
    }
    return obj;
  }
  // this logs the array containing "id" only.
console.log(processData(arr, "id"));
// this consoles the entire structure.
//console.log(processData(arr));
```

Comment: @RKumar Please validate, lemme know if you have any concerns.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question but this code might be a good start to identify your goal.

The `forEach` function can easily achieve this

```
var ids = [];
var names = [];
data.forEach(function(obj) {
 ids.push(obj.id);
 names.push(obj.name);
});
```

If you wan to use `map` function too

```
var ids = data.map(function(obj){
  return obj.id;
});

var names = data.map(function(obj){
  return obj.name;
});
```

But if you're aiming for cross compatibility. Use a normal `for` loop.

```
var ids = [];
var names = [];
for (var i in data) {
 ids.push(data[i].id);
 names.push(data[i].name);
}
```

Output

```
["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"] // ids

["name1", "name2", "name3", "name4", "name5"] // names
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [ { "id" : "1", "name" : "name1" }, { "id" : "2", "name" : "name2" }, { "id" : "3", "name" : "name3" }, { "id" : "4", "name" : "name4" }, { "id" : "5", "name" : "name5" } ];

var result = {
  name: [],
  id: []
};
data.forEach(d => {
  result.name.push(d.name);
  result.id.push(d.id);
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: You could also do that with `.reduce()`.

Comment: @Pointy `Array.prototype.reduce` should return something on every iteration.

Comment: Indeed it should. In this case, it would be the result object. Your way is fine too, don't get me wrong.

Comment: @Pointy I didn't. I think my implementations performance is better.